# Specify type from keyof type typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function

```
newText<T, U extends keyof T>(name: keyof T, value: T[U]){...}
```

If I call it with T looking like `{ one: Function, two: string }` the types should looks like `'one' | 'two'` for one and `Function | string` for value.

This is super close to what I want but when I specify a name I want the value to be the type of that key. So if I do `newText('one',` I would want to see `Function` as my only option for value and doing `newText('two', () =>{})` should throw an error.

Is this possible in typescript 2.6?

**Full use case with solution**

```
type params = {
  util?: Function;
  utilName?: string;
  other?: string;
};

type utilParams = 'util' | 'utilName';

class field {
  name: string;
  required: boolean;
  value: any;
  params: params;
  constructor(name: string, required: boolean, value: any, params: params) {
    this.name = name;
    this.required = required;
    this.value = value;
    this.params = params;
  }
}

type coreOptional<T, U extends keyof T> = {
  required?: boolean;
  value?: T[U];
};

class test<T> {
  test<U extends keyof T>(name: keyof T, optional: coreOptional<T, U> & Partial<Pick<params, utilParams>>) {
    let onlyParams: Partial<Pick<params, utilParams>> = { ...optional };
    return new field(name, optional.required || false, optional.value, onlyParams);
  }
}

let myTest = new test<{ one: Function; two: Function }>();

myTest.test('one', { value: '' }); //works!
myTest.test('one', { value: false}); //errors like it should.
```

Comment: use `U` instead of `keyof T` for the parameter? eg: `newText<T, U extends keyof T>(name: U, value: T[U]){...}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if I do newText('one', I would want to see Function as my only option for value and doing newText('two', () =>{}) should throw an error.

Simple:

```
type T = { one: Function, two: string };
declare function newText<KEY extends keyof T>(name: KEY, value: T[KEY]): any;

newText('one', () => null); // Okay
newText('two', () => null); // Error
```

Cheers

Comment: Yep that is what I thought. My actual use case is more complicated because  I am wrapping my class in some helper functions (I wanted to stay compatible with old usage so I couldn't change the types). doing this fixed my more complicated version. I added the full use case to the question.